# how to stop the screen rotation with out making changes to manifest

Tags: java, android

I have been developing an audits app and want one of my screens not to rotate using the sensors. I don't want to change the manifest but want to do this by using java
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To Make your application run only in portrait mode:

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

To Make your application run only in landscape mode:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

**Note: Use it before `setContentView` method.**

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following to restrict to specific orientation:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); // for portrait
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  // for landscape
```